# Model refresh if hasMany does not exist

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

### Information

So I have things setup like this

```
category 
    posts: hasMany {async: true}
```

Now I have lots and lots of categories.

I request all the categories from the server. In the response I don't include the `posts` fields because I'd need to query the server for all the ids of the posts that are related to the category. To get my response into something like this:

`categories: [{ other fields...., posts: [1,2,4,54,5]}, .... ]`

Anyway, I have another route that is for a specific category. For that I query the posts and do include it in the response.

However, if I am coming from the route that lists all the categories. That specific category is already loaded into the store and so it doesn't query for it. Issue is that it doesn't have the posts data.

### Question

How can I check if a field was present in a response or not, and subsequently do a model refresh to get the right data.

Comment: I guess you don't actually want to check fields in response. You want to know if you have `posts` or not, right?

Answer (score 0):

Since your hasMany relationship is `async`, Ember Data won't query `/posts` endpoint for related posts until you issue `category.get('posts')` or try to render category.

### Always Include Posts IDs

This way Ember Data handles the rest.

### Merge `posts` Field Whenever You Have to

Look at [Store#update](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_update)

Whenever you have posts ids

```
store.update('category', {id: categoryID, posts: [postIDs]})`
```

### Check if Category has any Posts and if It doesn't Reload It

To check if `posts` association is empty

```
category.get('posts').then(function(posts){
  posts.get('length') > 0;
});
```

And to reload it

```
category.get('posts').then(function(posts){
  if(posts.get('length') > 0){
    store.find('category', category.get('id'));
  }
});
```

Comment: I can't always include post ids sadly. When I am querying all the categories, I tested it and including post ids takes my 327ms wait to 4second wait. It's just not ideal. When I am doing store.update, I can just provide the array of post ids to the posts field? Also category.get('posts') won't return an error if there is no post ids?

Comment: Take a look at Store#update documentation, it expects an id and a payload to merge with fields in that id. + `category.get('posts')` will just return an empty array when post ids on payload is an empty array.